# Laravel Backpack - Tables options

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

is it possible read column data from database? example:

```
$this->crud->addField([
            'name'            => 'Price',
            'label'           => 'Options',
            'type'            => 'table',
            'entity_singular' => 'option', // used on the "Add X" button
            'columns'         => [
                'name'  => 'Country',
                'desc'  => 'Color',
                'price_from' => 'Price From',
                'price_to' => 'Price To',
            ],
            'max' => 5, // maximum rows allowed in the table
            'min' => 0, // minimum rows allowed in the table
        ]);
        
    }
```

is it possible to read Color from the colors table "black, white..etc" so the user selects the color from a dropdown menu instead of entering the color name?

[image]

Comment: from `table.blade.php` is **not possible** to make `selection` to the column, but you can make a custom one :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll be better served by [the `repeatable` field type](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#repeatable-1) here, instead of `table`.

The repeatable field type allows you to make a group of fields of different types (ex: `text`, `color_picker`, `number`), that will then be... repeatable. Basically a row of different fields, exactly like you're trying to create. The end user can then add more rows of the same type. I think it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I have already created a custom one :). I have deleted and now using the repeatable field type. Thanks, I really appreciated it!